# Does a mystic need to apply the same elemental glyph to each targeted ally?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, mystic, path-of-war

One of my players is playing a [Mystic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/path-of-war/classes/mystic).

His third level class feature, Elemental Glyph, lets him...

> apply an elemental glyph to a number of allies equal to her mystic initiation modifier modifier [sic] within her sight

Does he need to apply the same element to all the recipients of the glyph, or can he choose different elements for each recipient?

Comment: Huh. The text really does say *modifier modifier.* Weird. Maybe needs a *sic* unless *Path of War* describes how to determine a modifier's modifier?

Answer (score 1):

### As written, one Element must be chosen for each use of this ability, applied to a selection of allies.

The entire line for use of the [Elemental Glyph](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/path-of-war/classes/mystic/#TOC-Elemental-Glyph-Su-) class feature, with emphasis added:

> As a move action, the mystic can spend one point of animus to apply *an elemental glyph* to a number of allies equal to her mystic initiation modifier modifier within her sight.

This is different than choosing a number of allies to supply Elemental Glyphs *to*. Without specifying that you can change the glyphs selected for each target, you default to doing exactly what the text says.

It is unclear if this was intended to be the function, and you should speak with your GM if you feel it's more thematic or balanced to ignore. However, this *is* in-line with standard Pathfinder abilities, such as Communal spells and Bardic Performance.

Comment: I think that the grammar is arguable either way. Were it to've said *apply an identical elemental glyph* or *apply a different elemental glyph* then the reader would know with absolute certainty. However, *apply an elemental glyph* really can go either way. (Just pay the writer the extra $0.05 already, publishers! Yeesh!) With that in mind, I think the far stronger argument is that made from precedent—consider, though, adding a few more examples (e.g. I think a skald shares rage powers, and I think several classes share teamwork feats).

Comment: It's 3pp content, so I can see either way. Short of a clear reason to read it the other way, I default to this. I'll grab a couple more examples, thanks!